# Scarlet web socket library connection failed

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket

Just trying to get very basic websocket communication working between an Android app (Kotlin) and a NodeJS server.  The NodeJS server has been working and connecting with other clients without any issues.  The very basic code I have looks like this:

```
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HBASIC))
        .build()

    if (client != null) {
        val scarlet = Scarlet.Builder()
            .webSocketFactory(client.newWebSocketFactory("ws://192.168.2.33:3000"))
            .addMessageAdapterFactory(MoshiMessageAdapter.Factory())
            .addStreamAdapterFactory(RxJava2StreamAdapterFactory())
            .build()

        val myService = scarlet.create<MyService>()

        myService.observeWebSocketEvent()
            .subscribe { ev ->
                Log.e("WEB SOCKET", ev)
            }
    }
```

I get the following errors:

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://192.168.2.33:3000/
D/OkHttp: Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: ctY0bb8jl/mbF6KYGbSJBw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
--> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://192.168.2.33:3000/...
```

Just wondering if there is anything obvious that I'm doing wrong.  I'm using the following dependencies:

```
    implementation 'com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet:0.1.7'
    implementation 'com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-message-adapter-moshi:0.1.7'
    implementation 'com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-stream-adapter-rxjava2:0.1.7'
    implementation 'com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-websocket-okhttp:0.1.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.14.0'
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?